# Ubuntu installer doesn't see that Windows is already installed

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have this very weird problem. I installed Windows 7 Professional first on my machine ( But I didn't select all the memory space, so I left about 500GB for ubuntu), and I was able to install windows fine.

Then when I installed ubuntu from usb, it's not able to detect any OS installed when I have windows installed and it thought it has all 1TB space available.  Would anyone know why this is so? If I install ubuntu this way then my Windows is automatically erased...

Thanks!

Comment: Try the option `Something Else`, manually create the partitions. You may want to refer :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE8XvuhyaaA

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the disk has a GPT partition, this also happens when the user has Windows 8 with secure boot (UEFI) enabled. I faced that, and I did this

1- First, make sure that you don't have secure boot/UEFI enabled, you can check it in the bios

2- Boot ubuntu from USB

3- Open the disks utility

4- Delete all existing partitions of the desired disk, and press CTRL+F

5- Select MBR/DOS from the partitioning type, and then format

6- Make a ntfs partition using the whole drive

7- Shutdown Ubuntu and boot to the Windows 7 installer

8- When you're going to install, click on advanced/custom install (so you can edit 
partitions)

9- Select the ntfs partition that you created with ubuntu. DON'T delete that partition, install over it

10- After installing Windows 7, try to install ubuntu and see if the installer detects Windows 7.

I did that and after I was able to install Windows 7 and Ubuntu. You need to create a ntfs/mbr partition with ubuntu, because if you install Windows it will use GPT and as far I know ubuntu isn't very good when trying to get a dual boot when the disk has a GPT partition table.

Hope it help you. Cheers

Comment: I'm really giving up on this windows thing OMG, so after I did the first 6 steps, used the exact same usb and booted into windows install, BOMB : Windows can't be installed into selected disk this disk is of format GPT...

And I'm pretty sure you're right about the windows installation, but it just wouldn't boot into UEFI...and I have no idea why, I thought Windows can't be burned into a FAT32?but NTFP does not support UEFI...

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu on the other partition. Probably, the boot screen will not show you any Windows option and would login to ubuntu directly. Now, do the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Run boot repair and do the recommended repair. 
Verified for **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

Boot Repair is specially designed for this type of conditions. It is an easy to follow project. You can also visit [Boot Repair - Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home)